# Accessing EC2 Tags from inside a Windows Server instance using Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server

When using a Windows Server image is it possible to access the EC2 Tags from inside the instance itself using Powershell?

Comment: All EC2 instances can easily get the instance metadata such as tags via requests to 169.254.169.254: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: No, I don't think tags are included in the meta-data. I believe the Action API is required. I cant for the life of me work out how to get it working though...